# AMPScript Function UpdateSingleSalesforceObject Failure returning e500 instead of 0

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, error

I am working on a custom email preferences page and trying to handle a failure when AMPScript is attempting to update a salesforce record. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm) states that failure will return a value of 0 but instead it is just resolving to an error 500 page.

http://cloud.wines.maisondegrandesprit.com/preferences?subscriberKey=0034400001zsvXfAAI&HasOptedOutOfEmail=false&Do_Not_Mail__c=false&MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c=7&MC_Campaign_Unsubscribed_From__c=&

I changed the last character of the subscriberKey to 0034400001zsvXfAA9 to simulate an invalid record ID.

The condition I am trying to handle is on line 14 of the following block:

```
%%[
SET @subscriberKey = QUERYPARAMETER("subscriberKey")
IF (Length(@subscriberKey) == 18) THEN
    SET @HasOptedOutOfEmail = QUERYPARAMETER("HasOptedOutOfEmail")
    SET @Do_Not_Mail__c = QUERYPARAMETER("Do_Not_Mail__c")
    SET @MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c = QUERYPARAMETER("MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c")
    SET @MC_Campaign_Unsubscribed_From__c = QUERYPARAMETER("MC_Campaign_Unsubscribed_From__c")
    IF (
        (@HasOptedOutOfEmail != "" OR @HasOptedOutOfEmail IS NOT NULL) AND 
        (@Do_Not_Mail__c != "" OR @Do_Not_Mail__c IS NOT NULL) AND 
        (@MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c != "" OR @MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c IS NOT NULL)
    ) THEN
        VAR @updateStatus
        SET @updateStatus = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact',@subscriberKey,'HasOptedOutOfEmail',@HasOptedOutOfEmail,'Do_Not_Mail__c',@Do_Not_Mail__c,'MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c',@MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c,'MC_Campaign_Unsubscribed_From__c',@MC_Campaign_Unsubscribed_From__c)
        /* IF THIS CONDITION EVALUES TO TRUE, I WANT IT TO RETURN SET THE ERROR MESSAGE
        INSTEAD IT IS JUST AN ERROR 500 PAGE IF TRUE */
        IF (@updateStatus == 0) THEN
            SET @errorMessage = "Error: Contact could not be updated."
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
    SET @contact = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact","HasOptedOutOfEmail,Do_Not_Mail__c,FirstName,LastName,Email,MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c","Id", "=", @subscriberKey)
    IF (RowCount(@contact) > 0) THEN
        SET @emailOptOut = Field(Row(@contact,1),"HasOptedOutOfEmail")
        SET @mailOptOut = Field(Row(@contact,1),"Do_Not_Mail__c")
        SET @firstName = Field(Row(@contact,1),"FirstName")
        SET @lastName = Field(Row(@contact,1),"LastName")
        SET @email = Field(Row(@contact,1),"Email")
        SET @emailFrequency = Field(Row(@contact,1),"MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c")
        IF (@emailOptOut == "true") THEN
            SET @emailState = "fa-square-o"
        ELSE
            SET @emailState = "fa-check-square-o"
        ENDIF
        IF (@mailOptOut == "true") THEN
            SET @mailState = "fa-square-o"
        ELSE
            SET @mailState = "fa-check-square-o"
        ENDIF
    ELSE
        SET @errorMessage = "Error: Could not find a contact with that subscriberKey."
    ENDIF
ELSE
    SET @errorMessage = "Error: Invalid subscriberKey."
ENDIF
]%%
```

The full code of the page is here:

```
%%[
SET @subscriberKey = QUERYPARAMETER("subscriberKey")
IF (Length(@subscriberKey) == 18) THEN
    SET @HasOptedOutOfEmail = QUERYPARAMETER("HasOptedOutOfEmail")
    SET @Do_Not_Mail__c = QUERYPARAMETER("Do_Not_Mail__c")
    SET @MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c = QUERYPARAMETER("MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c")
    SET @MC_Campaign_Unsubscribed_From__c = QUERYPARAMETER("MC_Campaign_Unsubscribed_From__c")
    IF (
        (@HasOptedOutOfEmail != "" OR @HasOptedOutOfEmail IS NOT NULL) AND 
        (@Do_Not_Mail__c != "" OR @Do_Not_Mail__c IS NOT NULL) AND 
        (@MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c != "" OR @MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c IS NOT NULL)
    ) THEN
        VAR @updateStatus
        SET @updateStatus = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact',@subscriberKey,'HasOptedOutOfEmail',@HasOptedOutOfEmail,'Do_Not_Mail__c',@Do_Not_Mail__c,'MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c',@MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c,'MC_Campaign_Unsubscribed_From__c',@MC_Campaign_Unsubscribed_From__c)
        IF (@updateStatus == 0) THEN
            SET @errorMessage = "Error: Contact could not be updated."
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
    SET @contact = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact","HasOptedOutOfEmail,Do_Not_Mail__c,FirstName,LastName,Email,MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c","Id", "=", @subscriberKey)
    IF (RowCount(@contact) > 0) THEN
        SET @emailOptOut = Field(Row(@contact,1),"HasOptedOutOfEmail")
        SET @mailOptOut = Field(Row(@contact,1),"Do_Not_Mail__c")
        SET @firstName = Field(Row(@contact,1),"FirstName")
        SET @lastName = Field(Row(@contact,1),"LastName")
        SET @email = Field(Row(@contact,1),"Email")
        SET @emailFrequency = Field(Row(@contact,1),"MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c")
        IF (@emailOptOut == "true") THEN
            SET @emailState = "fa-square-o"
        ELSE
            SET @emailState = "fa-check-square-o"
        ENDIF
        IF (@mailOptOut == "true") THEN
            SET @mailState = "fa-square-o"
        ELSE
            SET @mailState = "fa-check-square-o"
        ENDIF
    ELSE
        SET @errorMessage = "Error: Could not find a contact with that subscriberKey."
    ENDIF
ELSE
    SET @errorMessage = "Error: Invalid subscriberKey."
ENDIF
]%%
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>
      Communication Preferences - Maison De Grand Esprit
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FAVICONS -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://image.wines.maisondegrandesprit.com/lib/fe9112737467067b7c/m/1/d89acd80-25c1-4fde-bcf2-beeb021a686f.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="180x180" href="http://image.wines.maisondegrandesprit.com/lib/fe9112737467067b7c/m/1/04f48c3f-580f-44ad-ac3c-d41c37a9b427.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="http://image.wines.maisondegrandesprit.com/lib/fe9112737467067b7c/m/1/007a3774-7bc3-41bb-86e1-4428c87e1ee6.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="http://image.wines.maisondegrandesprit.com/lib/fe9112737467067b7c/m/1/2a6f2cf0-6d6d-469e-8ed7-d54966aec329.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="http://image.wines.maisondegrandesprit.com/lib/fe9112737467067b7c/m/1/fa58ab80-72f3-439b-8439-f36824882f94.png" />
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- MC Assets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%%=CloudPagesURL(1379)=%%">
    <script>
      //set up globals from MC
      const contact = {};
      contact.subscriberKey = "%%=v(@subscriberKey)=%%";
      contact.HasOptedOutOfEmail = %%=v(@emailOptOut)=%%;
      contact.Do_Not_Mail__c = %%=v(@mailOptOut)=%%;
      contact.MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c = %%=v(@emailFrequency)=%%;
      contact.MC_Campaign_Unsubscribed_From__c = "%%=QUERYPARAMETER("MC_Campaign_Unsubscribed_From__c")=%%";
    </script>
  </head>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var d = new Date();
        //fix size of logo for navbar-toggler to remain inline
        $(".navbar-brand img").css("max-width", window.outerWidth - ($(".navbar-brand").position().left + $(".navbar-brand").css("margin-right").replace(/\D/gi, "") * 1 + $(".navbar-toggler").outerWidth(true) + (window.outerWidth * 0.075)));
        //match height of nav
        $(".y-top-nav-container").height($(".y-top-nav").outerHeight());
        if ($(".navbar-toggler").css("display") === "block") {
            $(".y-top-nav").css("background", "url('http://image.wines.maisondegrandesprit.com/lib/fe9112737467067b7c/m/1/a2af575d-9d7c-4baa-8b81-de43ff6ef69e.png') repeat");
        }
        //add oc year
        $(".y-year").html(d.getFullYear());
        //fix min height
        $(".y-main-content").css("top", $(".y-top-nav").outerHeight()).css("min-height", window.innerHeight - $(".y-footer-container").outerHeight() - $(".y-top-nav-container").outerHeight());
        //change contstant properties for email and mail opt in and out
        $(".y-fa-checkbox").each(function() {
            $(this).on("click", function() {
                toggleThis(this);
            });
        });
        //pre set email frequency preference
        $("[data-y-bind='MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c'] option[value=" + contact.MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
        //change frequency preference
        $("[data-y-bind='MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c']").on("change", function() {
            contact.MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c = $(this).val();
        });
        // handle submission
        $(".btn-default:contains('Submit')").on("click", function() {
            document.location.href = document.location.href.split("?")[0] + "?" + returnKeyValString(contact, "=", "&");
        });
    });
    //end doc ready
    //toggle checkbox and assign contact values
    function toggleThis(a) {
        if (a.className.indexOf("fa-square-o") > -1) {
            if ($(a).attr("data-y-bind") === "HasOptedOutOfEmail") {
                contact.HasOptedOutOfEmail = false;
            } else if ($(a).attr("data-y-bind") === "Do_Not_Mail__c") {
                contact.Do_Not_Mail__c = false;
            }
            $(a).addClass("fa-check-square-o").removeClass("fa-square-o");
        } else if (a.className.indexOf("fa-check-square-o") > -1) {
            if ($(a).attr("data-y-bind") === "HasOptedOutOfEmail") {
                contact.HasOptedOutOfEmail = true;
            } else if ($(a).attr("data-y-bind") === "Do_Not_Mail__c") {
                contact.Do_Not_Mail__c = true;
            }
            $(a).addClass("fa-square-o").removeClass("fa-check-square-o");
        }
    }
    //return string of key value pairs with delimiters
    function returnKeyValString(object, keyDelimiter, pairDelimiter) {
        var kVs = "";
        var k = Object.keys(object);
        for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
            kVs += k[i] + keyDelimiter + object[k[i]] + pairDelimiter;
        }
        return kVs;
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <!-- START TOP NAV -->
    <div class="container-fluid y-top-nav-container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top container y-top-nav">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.maisondegrandesprit.com/">
          <img src="http://image.wines.maisondegrandesprit.com/lib/fe9112737467067b7c/m/1/e1afaa56-e573-46d9-9626-1b7cc45ba6eb.png" alt="Logo" style="width:300px;">
        </a>  
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="collapsibleNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.maisondegrandesprit.com/en-us/wines/all-wines/all-wines">Wines</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.maisondegrandesprit.com/en-us/winemaker">Winemaker</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item d-md-none d-lg-block">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.maisondegrandesprit.com/en-us/awards">Scores &amp; Awards</a>
            </li>  
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.maisondegrandesprit.com/en-us/news">News</a>
            </li>    
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.maisondegrandesprit.com/en-us/contact">Contact</a>
            </li>  
          </ul>
        </div>  
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- END TOP NAV -->
    <!-- START MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="container y-main-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h4>
            %%=Concat(@firstName, " ", @lastName)=%%
          </h4>
          <h5>
            %%=v(@email)=%%
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row y-pref-row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <i class="fa %%=v(@emailState)=%% y-fa-checkbox" data-y-bind="HasOptedOutOfEmail">
          </i>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope y-fa-icon">
          </i>Email
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" data-y-bind="MC_Preferred_Email_Frequency__c">
              <option value="0">Email Frequency (All)</option>
              <option value="7">Weekly</option>
              <option value="30">Monthly</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <span style="font-size:0.7em;">Please note that we are required to send transactional emails such as purchase confirmations and wine club communications regardless of email preferences.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row y-pref-row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <i class="fa %%=v(@mailState)=%% y-fa-checkbox" data-y-bind="Do_Not_Mail__c">
          </i>
          <i class="fa fa-home y-fa-icon">
          </i>Mail
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <a class="btn btn-default">Submit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END MAIN CONTENT -->
    <!-- START FOOTER -->
    <div class="container-fluid y-footer-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h5 style="color: #fff; padding-top: 24px;">&copy; 
            <span class="y-year"></span> Maison De Grand Esprit
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark container justify-content-center y-footer">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.maisondegrandesprit.com/">
          <img src="http://image.wines.maisondegrandesprit.com/lib/fe9112737467067b7c/m/1/e1afaa56-e573-46d9-9626-1b7cc45ba6eb.png" alt="Logo" style="width:300px;">
        </a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.maisondegrandesprit.com/en-us/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.maisondegrandesprit.com/en-us/terms-and-conditions">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="htthttps://www.maisondegrandesprit.com/en-us/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
          </li>  
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.maisondegrandesprit.com/en-us/contact">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <img src="http://image.wines.maisondegrandesprit.com/lib/fe9112737467067b7c/m/1/4a73197f-53cd-4f4a-9969-ac9e7818ac21.png" style="color: #fff; padding-bottom: 24px; height: 75px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END FOOTER -->
  </body>
</html>
```